# Function not returning Value in angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the second function return value in ngOnInit, but it's giving undefined. If I print SvgImage its printing. I don't know where I did the mistake.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.userService.displayEvents(this.user_id).subscribe(data => {
  this.eventArray = [];
  if (data.status == 'success') {
    data.result.forEach(obj => {
      let item = {
        id: obj.id,
        user_id: obj.user_id,
        name: obj.name,
        image: this.getSvgImage(obj.category, obj.color_code),
        category: obj.category,
        start_date: obj.start_date,
        status: obj.status,
      };
      this.eventArray.push(item);
    });
    this.displayEvents = this.eventArray;
    console.log(this.displayEvents);
  }
});
}

getSvgImage(categoryID: any, colorCode: any) {
this.userService.getEventCategory().subscribe((data) => {
  let SvgImage: any = "";
  if (data.status == "success") {
    data.result.forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.id == categoryID) {
        let color = colorCode.replace("#", "");
        let SvgImageReplace = obj.image.split('#').pop().split(';')[0];
        SvgImage = obj.image.replace(SvgImageReplace, color);
        SvgImage = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(SvgImage);
      }
    });
  }
  return SvgImage;
});
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that SvgImage in getSvgImage function returns undefined or is the image property of item that is undefined because the getEventCategory() has not returned when the item.image gets the value?

Comment: I am sure, I am printing the SvgImage in the console. It's coming but the same value is not returning from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following mods:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.displayEvents(this.user_id).subscribe(data => {
        this.eventArray = [];
        if (data.status == 'success') {
            data.result.forEach(obj => {
                let item = {
                    id: obj.id,
                    user_id: obj.user_id,
                    name: obj.name,
                    image: '',
                    category: obj.category,
                    start_date: obj.start_date,
                    status: obj.status,
                };
                this.eventArray.push(item);
                this.getSvgImage(item, obj.category, obj.color_code),
            });
            this.displayEvents = this.eventArray;
            console.log(this.displayEvents);
        }
    });
}

getSvgImage(item, categoryID: any, colorCode: any) {
    this.userService.getEventCategory().subscribe((data) => {
        let SvgImage: any = "";
        if (data.status == "success") {
            data.result.forEach(obj => {
                if (obj.id == categoryID) {
                    let color = colorCode.replace("#", "");
                    let SvgImageReplace = obj.image.split('#').pop().split(';')[0];
                    SvgImage = obj.image.replace(SvgImageReplace, color);
                    SvgImage = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(SvgImage);
                }
            });
        }
        item.image = SvgImage;
    });
}
```

getSvgImage will get as it's first param the item object and once the subscription completes it will update the image property.

Answer (score 1):

The function `getSvgImage` does not return anything. The invocation `this.userService.getEventCategory().subscribe((data) => { ... })` creates a `Subscription` but you don't event return it.

Comment: Yes, It's not returning anything.

Comment: Well, do return something then, if that's what you want! :-D